# Make IntelliJ and Maven Use the Same Classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Could I take the time to painstakingly debug these problems and fix them? Yes. Have I already spent a ton of time doing just this, and yet continue to find a rabbit hole of random issues? Yes. I'm hoping there is an easy solution.

I work at a very, very big company. Our Java stack is full of enterprise dependencies, with their own convoluted web of transitive dependencies. This becomes a problem when running with IntelliJ's runner vs Maven's runner.

If I do mvn spring-boot:run, everything always works. Period. Not only does it work locally, the bundled jar deployed in our cloud environment works.

When I run with IntelliJ, however, things get screwy. All the problems are completely related to how IntelliJ sets up its classpath. Dependency conflicts are handled differently, libraries are loaded in different orders leading to weird impacts with certain enterprise-y resources, etc.

All I want is to make IntelliJ basically do mvn spring-boot:run, but still with the option to automatically attach a debugger.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use IntelliJ's Maven runner? The debugger should be attachable to this type of run configuration, if I'm not completely mistaken. Also, did you configure IntelliJ to automatically load the dependencies from your POM? (That is, did you import the project as a Maven project?)

Comment: That doesn't attach the debugger. IntelliJ is loading the dependencies from maven, but the Spring Runner is doing something funky with the classpath.

Comment: The setting "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven" should do exactly what you want: IDEA will leave all building and running to Maven, making sure you use the exact same setup as if you manually build/run.

Comment: Where is that setting?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to debug Spring Boot project from the `boot:run` Maven goal right from the Maven tool window:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work well enough, generally need CLI args